# replace string variable in Scala for solution

Tags: scala

I have a variable which has the following data structure, I want to replace all "foo" with all "goo" for the `String` part. Is there any one line neat code to do that? Want to see if any smart solutions to skip to write a loop. :)

```
var result = List[List[(List[String], Double)]]
```

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> val l = List(List((List("foo","afoo"),3.4),(List("gfoo","cfoo"),5.6)))
l: List[List[(List[String], Double)]] = List(List((List(foo, afoo),3.4), (List(gfoo, cfoo),5.6)))

scala> def replaceFoo(y:List[String]) = y.map(s => s.replace("foo","goo"))
replaceFoo: (y: List[String])List[String]

scala> l.map(x => x.map(y => (replaceFoo(y._1),y._2)))
res0: List[List[(List[String], Double)]] = List(List((List(goo, agoo),3.4), (List(ggoo, cgoo),5.6)))
```

Comment: Thanks Andrzej, always vote up before trying. :)

Appreciate if you could elaborate a bit more for what this line means `l.map(x => x.map(y => (y._1.map(s => s.replace("foo","goo")),y._2)))`? Still seems a bit advanced to me. :)

Comment: Method replaceFoo - replace all foo to goo in list. This list is a first element of tuple (List[String],Double). About first element of tuple ask as _1, about second _2

Comment: Thanks Andrzej for the patience, mark your reply as answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if I got it right but maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
scala> val a: List[List[(List[String], Double)]] = List(List((List("foo asd", "asd foo"), 2.6)))
scala> a map (_ map { case (k, v) => (k map (_.replaceAll("foo", "goo")), v) })
res1: List[List[(List[String], Double)]] = List(List((List(goo asd, asd goo),2.6)))
```

#### Edit

to answer the comment let me first remove spaces and use dots

```
scala> a.map(_.map { case (k, v) => (k.map(_.replaceAll("foo", "goo")), v) })
```

and now, expand `_.method(param)` to `x => x.method(param)`

```
scala> a.map(b => b.map { case (k, v) => (k.map(c => c.replaceAll("foo", "goo")), v) })
```

You have 3 levels of nested lists, and one is inside a tuple, it won't be pretty, you need to map over each of them and extract last one from tuple.

Comment: Thanks Łukasz, vote up and what means `_` in `_ map`?

Comment: See my edit, it is just a shorthand for more consise anonymous function